# Apache Storm UI visualisation window not working

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology, apache-storm-configs

I get this error trying to open the visualisation window in apache storm UI and it shows an empty page

> "org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size
> (35307746) larger than max length (1048576)"

apache storm version: 2.4.0